# cocos2d-x plugin-x compilation errors

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to compile for Android on Windows, I've executed `publish.sh` and `gameDevGuide.sh` successfully.

my `Android.mk` has been modified by `gameDevGuide.sh`

When I run `build_native.py` I get the following error:

> D:\cocos-projects\game\proj.android>build_native.py The Selected NDK
>   toolchain version was 4.8 ! Android NDK:
>
> ERROR:D:\cocos-projects\game\proj.android../cocos2d/plugin/publish/protocols/android/Android.mk:PluginProtocolStatic:
>   LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file Android NDK: Check that
>
> D:\cocos-projects\game\proj.android../cocos2d/plugin/publish/protocols/android/./lib/armeabi/libPluginProtocolStatic.a
>   exists

D:\cocos-projects\game\proj.android../cocos2d/plugin/publish/protocols/android/Android.mk contains:

> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS) LOCAL_MODULE := PluginProtocolStatic
>   LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libPluginProtocolStatic
>
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libPluginProtocolStatic.a
>   LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include $(LOCAL_PATH)
>   LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -llog
>
> include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

The path `D:\cocos-projects\game\proj.android../cocos2d/plugin/publish/protocols/android/./lib/armeabi/libPluginProtocolStatic.a` seems wrong (notice the dot). `libPluginProtocolStatic.a` does not exist

Any idea how do I fix that? (Cocos2d-x 3.2alpha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says it's pointing to a missing NDK, I'd guess you moved or renamed the folder your android stuff is in.  Run your setup.py the same way you did the first time (or if you never have, that's why).

Comment: Hey, I ran setup.py, the environment variables are set correctly. The problem remains, the project used to compile, but I'm trying to add plugin-x to the project which resulted in the described errors. If I clean up Android.mk it will build the project, but I need plugin-x in my project for admob and IAP.

Comment: Hmm, and you've tried cleaning the project?  Sometimes all you can do is start an entirely new project and dump all the code and resources in.  Sometimes there's just some pointer somewhere that got lost where a file got accidentally removed or renamed, and the internal library is still pointing to it.  Have you tried just removing the reference to the libPluginProtocolStatic.a file?  That must have gotten moved or renamed somehow.  See if you can get a fresh copy.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that plugins are publish correctly?
On windows you must have "make" command cygwin.
Try to open cygwin and write "make".